# Insert note to remember the info of a project

Tags: qgis, shapefile, file-formats, metadata, infrastructure

Sometimes I need to open an old project, and mostly I remember how it works (i.e. the structure, the formatting and so on) but sometimes not.

At other times I open a project composed by a colleague of mine and it is hard to understand how the project was conceived.

Is it possible to insert in the project a non-printable note to help to understand the project more quickly?

edit: I use QGIS 1.8 (2.0 soon) on Windows 7

Comment: I normally write note for single layer in Metadata tab

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using to try and do this?  I recommend you edit your Question to include that important detail.

Comment: Its a particularly strange set of tags too, so expanding how those relate to your question might be useful.

Comment: Sounds like a README file to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Quantum GIS (QGIS) v 2.0 I would recommend the qNote plugin.  It will create a dockable window in your project that you can use to save notes about a project. Go to Plugins>Manage and Install Plugins, select Get More and then search for qNote in the plugin manager console.

If you are using ArcGIS Desktop, go to File>Map Document Properties.  You can fill in the Summary and Description fields with any relevant information about the map.  This is saved with the map document, so anyone who opens it can access it.

Comment: I edited the question: I useo QGIS on windows 7

Comment: It works well! An hint for new users: when you close that window you can re-open it by view toolbar/panels/qNote

Answer (score 0):

Just make a CVS file and place it top-level in your projects layers. Result:
[image: ...]

To make it work, place a semicolon in the first line, creating the columnheader. For example:

```
Info;
First line
Second
...
```